# BLOB/TEXT column 'NormalizedName' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

I created a new .NetCore 6 project.

I try to migrate the first migration with Identity tables. I had an error for NormalizedName column:

> BLOB/TEXT column 'NormalizedName' used in key specification without a key length

I understand the error, the problem is field already has a maxLength of 256 in the CreateIdentitySchema.

What am I missing?

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetRoles",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    }, constraints: table =>
       {
           table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
       }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as MySQL is concerned, that "maxLength" is meaningless. `BLOB` and `TEXT` always have a max length of 64KB.

There is syntax to declare a "length" for `BLOB` or `TEXT`, but this does not define the maximum length. It defines a *minimum* length.

For example, if you declare a column `TEXT(1000000)`, that's greater than 64KB, so it automatically promotes the column to `MEDIUMTEXT`. Likewise if you declare `TEXT(1000000000)`, it becomes a `LONGTEXT`.

The error is related to the limit on index prefix length, which is independent from the length that can be stored in a column. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-prefix. Defining an index prefix is necessary for BLOB or TEXT, because the size of a BLOB or TEXT is greater than the maximum size for an index (3072 bytes in the current version of MySQL, 768 bytes in older versions).

I have no idea how to declare an index prefix through the migration builder interface.

Comment: I see thank you. I'm new in .NETCore, its migration process is strange.